Next.js Image Error: Invalid src prop (https://picsum.photos/200) on `next/image`
I have an image issue in my nextjs application that it was working yesterday. The error is simple and clear:
Error: Invalid src prop (https://picsum.photos/200) on `next/image`, hostname "picsum.photos" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js`
See more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host

I configured the url in next.config.js file and it was working. Today, I opened the project and get the error. The interesting part is this is working in another computer. Also, I reinstalled .next and node_modules but this did not resolve the issue either.
next.config.js file:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  basePath: "",
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "gittjeqpqcmmbterylkd.supabase.co",
        port: "",
        pathname: "/**",
      },
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "picsum.photos",
        port: "",
        pathname: "/**",
      },
    ],
  },
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.alias.canvas = false;

    return config;
  },
};


try this images: {   remotePatterns: [{ hostname: "*" }]  } if error gone then try to fix your pattern.

I have just realized that I forgot to export the file. Thanks for your answer though
